# Substring of a string from a point where character starts to repeat

Tags: python, algorithm

I am a sophomore CS student and I was practicing for interviews. In this problem, I am trying to print substring of an input parameter from the point where character starts to repeat. In other words, for a string like 'college', i want to print 'col', 'lege', 'colleg', 'e'.

The code implementation is shown below, but I wanted to ask about how to think of solving these types of problems, because they are really tricky and I wanted to know if there are certain algorithms to get hang of these dynamic problems quickly.

```
def checkrepeat(word):
i = 0
temp_w =''
check_char = {}
my_l = list()
while i < len(word)-1:
    if word[i] not in check_char:
        temp_w += word[i]
        check_char[word[i]] = i
    else:
        my_l.append(temp_w)
        temp_w=''
        i = check_char[word[i]]
        check_char.pop(word[i])
    i+=1
return my_l

print(checkrepeat('college'))
```

Comment: What's the logic behind getting `colle` and `ge` ?

Comment: So the logic is that, whenever the character we are dealing with starts to repeat, we slice the string to 2 substrings. For example: in case of 'bloomberg', we have 2 repeating characters 'b' and 'o'. So when we are dealing with 'b', we should print 'bloom','berg', and when we are dealing with 'o' , we should return, 'blo','omberg'. Hope I was clear.

Comment: For college, the program should return, 'col', 'lege' , 'colleg' and 'e'. I mistakenly gave the incorrect example in the body of my question which I corrected.

Comment: What happens if a letter occurs more than twice? Would `systems` become `'sy', 'stems'` or `'sy', 'stem, 's'`?

Comment: @asongtoruin it will have 3 substrings in that case. The later example you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT2 - The Working Solution, that's semi-elegant and almost Pythonic:

```
def split_on_recursion(your_string, repeat_character): #Recursive function
    temp_string = ''
    i = 0
    for character in your_string:
        if repeat_character == character:
            if i==1:
                return split_on_recursion(temp_string, repeat_character) #Recursion
            else:                                                        
                i += 1
        temp_string += character
    return temp_string

def split_on_repeat(your_string):
    temp_dict = {}
    your_dict = {}
    your_end_strings = []
    for char in set(your_string):
        temp_dict[char] = your_string.count(char) #Notice temp_dict

    for key in temp_dict:
        if temp_dict[key] >= 2:
            your_dict[key] = temp_dict[key] #Isolate only the characters which repeat

    if your_dict != {}:
        for key in your_dict:
            pre_repeat_string = split_on_recursion(your_string,key)
            post_repeat_string = your_string.replace(pre_repeat_string,'')
            your_end_strings.append((pre_repeat_string, post_repeat_string))
    else:
       your_end_strings = [(your_string)]

    return your_end_strings
```

Use:

```
>>> print(split_on_repeat('Innocent'))
[('In', 'nocent')]
>>> print(split_on_repeat('College'))
[('Colleg', 'e'), ('Col', 'lege')]
>>> print(split_on_repeat('Python.py'))
[('Python.p', 'y')]
>>> print(split_on_repeat('Systems'))
[('System', 's')]
```

As is the case, the solution is case-sensitive, but that is a minor issue.

To fathom the solution, though, you need to understand how recursions work. If you don't, this might not be a great example; I would recommend people to start with math problems.

But here's some quick context about how indexing works in python:

`'Word'[:1] == 'Wo'`

`'Word'[-1] == 'd'`

`'Word'[:-1] == 'Wor'`

This indexing works for every object that is indexable.

Comment: Very intuitive answer

Comment: I need to disclose that the initial answer had a bug though, in the `if` statement :)

And also, this works only on the first repeat of each letter.

Thank you for the checked answer though.

Comment: @ShrijanAryal I dunno why you've validated this answer but I don't think it works for all use-cases properly. Neither split_repeat nor split_on_repeat, so... just saying :)

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on the original post, how would this deal with the word `systems`?

Comment: Edit2 now live... But there is a much more elegant solution proposed by @fl00r http://stackoverflow.com/a/40563553/6159368

Comment: Now, this answer is best suited to be validated, even if it's not the most elegant one, it works with all use-cases and it's reasonably fast with long random strings (ie: len=10000000). Good job fixing the old version

Answer (score 1):

This may not be best practice, but it seems functional:

```
def checkrepeat(word):
    for letter in set(word):
        split_word = []
        copyword = word
        while copyword.count(letter) > 1:
            split_loc = copyword.rfind(letter)
            split_word.insert(0, copyword[split_loc:])
            copyword = copyword[:split_loc]

        if len(split_word) > 0:
            split_word.insert(0, copyword)
            print split_word

checkrepeat('college')
```

`set(word)` gives us a list of the unique characters in `word`. We create an empty list (`split_word`) to maintain the separate sections of the word. `count` lets us count the number of times a letter appears in a word - we want to split our word until every substring contains the given `letter` only once.

We iterate over a copy of `word` (as we need to repeat the exercise for each duplicated letter, thus don't want to tamper with the original `word` variable), and add the end-section of the word from our `letter` onwards to the start of our list. We repeat this until `copyword` only has our `letter` in it once, at which point we exit the `while` loop. The remaining characters of `copyword` must be added to the start of our list, and we print the word given. This example prints:

```
['colleg', 'e']
['col', 'lege']
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution derived from original @asongtoruin's idea:

```
import collections


def checkrepeat(word):
    out = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for c in word:
        out[c] += 1
    out = {k: [] for (k, v) in out.items() if v > 1}

    for letter, split_word in out.iteritems():
        copyword = word

        while copyword.count(letter) > 1:
            split_loc = copyword.rfind(letter)
            split_word.insert(0, copyword[split_loc:])
            copyword = copyword[:split_loc]

        if len(split_word) > 0:
            split_word.insert(0, copyword)

    return out

for word in ["bloomberg", "college", "systems"]:
    print checkrepeat(word)
```

Output:

```
{'b': ['bloom', 'berg'], 'o': ['blo', 'omberg']}
{'e': ['colleg', 'e'], 'l': ['col', 'lege']}
{'s': ['sy', 'stem', 's']}
```

Comment: The returning string in the list in the dict in your code is both lowered and it splits the string on all occurrences after the second one, instead of just a split once it repeats.

And while it works it's really a mess by python standards. Not a good example by any stretch.

Comment: @DavidLipnik Not sure what you mean when you say a "mess by python standards", this code is probably not the best way to address the problem, I'm sure of it, there are quite a lot of other more optimal solutions and elegant solutions. On the other hand, it handles ok all exposed use-cases by OP's requirements&comments, your "validated" solutions on the other hand doesn't. Not saying the OP should validate this solution but definitely the fact he validated yours it's a clear sympton he didn't test it properly.

Comment: Yes, but as the question was about principals and use of python for working with similar issues, your frankenstein monster of a solution covers none of the question ... My solution is now fixed, and in proper Python style.

Comment: @DavidLipnik Lol, not sure why you get so harsh  with your reactions, did I lie saying your first version of the code wasn't suitable to be validated? As a result now you've improved it "almost" properly, still  quite long code, but it's quite fast... Btw, this version is derived from asongtoruin's original version, not my own idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_repeated(string):
  visited = set()
  res = []
  for i, c in enumerate(string):
    if c in visited: res.append([string[0:i], string[i:]]) 
    visited.add(c)
  return res
```

Output:

```
split_repeated("college")
#=> [['col', 'lege'], ['colleg', 'e']]
split_repeated("hello world")
#=> [['hel', 'lo world'], ['hello w', 'orld'], ['hello wor', 'ld']]
```

If you need to split a string only when you meet repeated letter first time:

```
def split_repeated_unique(string):
  visited = set()
  shown = set()
  res = []
  for i, c in enumerate(string):
    if c in visited:
      if c not in shown:
        res.append([string[0:i], string[i:]])
        shown.add(c)
    else:
      visited.add(c)
  return res
```

And the key difference is following:

```
split_repeated("Hello, Dolly")
#=> [('Hel', 'lo, Dolly'), ('Hello, D', 'olly'), ('Hello, Do', 'lly'), ('Hello, Dol', 'ly')]
split_repeated_unique("Hello, Dolly")
#=> [['Hel', 'lo, Dolly'], ['Hello, D', 'olly']]
```

Comment: ... I always forget enumerate. Very nice solution, I recommend for working solution.

Comment: I must to say this is a really elegant solution, but I still prefer @DavidLipnik's one, if you use random long strings with this one it'll take forever. If i have to choose between elegant code vs slow one, I'll pick up the faster one ;)

Comment: @BPL it is `~O(N)` solution. Why is it slow one?

Comment: @floor Try with this one `import random; random.seed(1); word = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10000000))`, David's version run it on ~9s.

Comment: hey man, you're starting to grow on me @BPL ... but as I'm trying to stay true to zen of python:
>Beautiful is better than ugly.
comes before
>Explicit is better than implicit.
:)

Comment: @DavidLipnik Haha, cool, sorry if my first comment felt bad to you, English is not my mother tongue but I didn't want you to get offended at all. If I see something it can be improved I'll point it out, so the whole community will benefit about the improvements and learn a little bit about it, peace :)

Comment: @BPL the issue here is not in performance. You can't compare them directly. Because they return different output. I don't know which result author wanted, but in my solution, it will return new substrings each time it meets repeated letter, while DavidLipnik's solution returns it only once.

Comment: @BPL I'm sorry for the harsh reaction, but I was just put off by the fact that I'm a newbie on stackoverflow, while you're rocking at 5k reputation, and instead of trying to point me in the right direction or at least investing the time to point out where the code sidetracks you merely said it yields wrong results.

Comment: @DavidLipnik Definitely you're right, thanks for letting me know, next time I'll be more careful with my comments :) "you lie down without ever knowing one more thing" .

Comment: @BPL I've added the same interpretation of the task as David did. `split_repeated_unique`. One can boost it's performance by using less idiomatic Python, but I am not a fan of this kind of approach.

Comment: @fl00r Awesome job! And yeah, you're right, i understand what you mean, **sometimes** is a tradeoff between `elegancy vs performance`. It all depends the type of input you expect to be using in your use-cases. In any case, even if I like the python's zen I always try to stick to the `what get the jobs done` rule, OP's was mentioning something about practicing for interview, which answer do you think it would give him the job? Let's say the interviewer told him "Wow, you snippet is amazing, is just 2 lines... but... i can't use this in production, sorry, you're not getting the job"

Comment: @BPL, my point was slightly different. `split_repeated` and `split_repeated_unique` solve different tasks :) you can't take one fast solution if it doesn't solve the problem in the way you need. So again. The first function splits on each repetition while the second one splits only on the first repetition. Although I think the second one is what author needed (`where character starts to repeat`).